# Terraria fishing rod for Android

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have Terraria for my Android, and when I try to make a fishing pole it never works. I have all the items I need and I'm next to a crafting station, but it won't show up in the craft list.

Answer (score 1):

Which crafting station are you standing next to?  The Wooden Rod requires 8 wood and a work bench.  Are you sure you're standing next to that?  Maybe pick up and relocate the table if it's next to a bunch of other crafting stations.  This will de-clutter the crafting interface.

Comment: I'm using a plain wood crafting station and I de-cluttered it and still no luck

Answer (score -1):

Try standing directly above the crafting station since the crafting mechanism for Terraria Mobile is not that great as compared to the PC or console.